# How to add pagination with axios using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, pagination

Could you help me how to create pagination on my project, I already display the data on the table and the search is working fine. Im using class extends component also with axios, and i don't know how to paginate table, I think I've done a lot of tutorials code how to paginate, then I still can't get it.

This is the code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import Users from "../Users";

class UsersManagement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      search: "",
      sort: ["Oldest", "Newest"],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost/crud-user/php/users.php")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ users: res.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  displayUsers() {
    return this.state.users
      .filter(
        (user) =>
          user.first_name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          user.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
      )
      .map(function (object, index) {
        return <Users obj={object} key={index} />;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div className="w-full text-center leading-10 mt-10">
          <span className="text-black not-italic font-extrabold text-5xl">
            USER MANAGEMENT
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="md:px-32 w-screen mt-10">
          <div className="flex overflow-hidden w-10/12 mx-auto">
            <div className="w-full mb-5">
              <Search
                onSearch={(e) => this.setState({ search: e.target.value })}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="w-full mb-5 text-right">
              <select
                name="sort"
                value={this.props.sort}
                onChange={this.props.onChangeSort}
                className="border-2 border-black rounded-xl h-12 px-5 outline-none cursor-pointer"
              >
                {this.state.sort.map((sort) => (
                  <option className="cursor-pointer" value={sort}>
                    {sort}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="overflow-hidden w-10/12 mx-auto">
            <table className="min-w-full bg-white">
              <thead className="bg-white text-black border-b-2 border-gray-500">
                <tr>
                  <th className="w-1/5 text-left py-3 px-4 font-semibold text-lg">
                    User ID
                  </th>
                  <th className="w-1/4 text-left py-3 px-4 font-semibold text-lg">
                    Name
                  </th>
                  <th className="w-1/4 text-left py-3 px-4 font-semibold text-lg">
                    E-mail
                  </th>
                  <th className="text-center py-3 px-4 font-semibold text-lg">
                    Phone Number
                  </th>
                  <th className="text-center py-3 px-4 font-semibold text-lg">
                    Birthdate
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody className="text-black">
                {this.displayUsers().length > 0 ? (
                  this.displayUsers()
                ) : (
                  <p className="mt-5 text-lg text-red-700 cursor-default">
                    No data available!
                  </p>
                )}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UsersManagement;
```

For the CSS, Im using tailwind CSS Framework. Thanks much help!

Comment: this is a lot of code, can you try to narrow it down to isolate the problem, heres a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you can use Pagination component from ant design. https://ant.design/components/pagination/

Comment: @AR Thanks, but how to apply this on my code, do you know how to do it?

Comment: It's very easy, just follow along the sample code given in the documentation